# Dynamic column class for Zurb-Foundation columns using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Foundations with AngularJS. I have a case where I'm trying to display things in columns using `ng-repeat`.

```
<div class="four columns" ng-repeat="resultsObject in resultsObject">
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="resultsObject"></div>
</div>
```

This works fine. But the issue is that the columns size could be anywhere from 1-5. And I'd like the display to update dynamically. So if there are only 2 columns, it would adjust to the correctly column display.

```
<div class="{{$rootScope.columnCount}} columns" ng-repeat="resultsObject in resultsObject">
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="resultsObject"></div>
</div>
```

When I try doing something like the above code, `{{$rootScope.columnCount}}` doesn't display anything. (I have verified that it does accurately store the correct column based on input.) It shows up in the source as `<div class=" columns">` instead of `<div class="3 columns">`.

Is this an issue with using an angular variable and `ng-repeat` in the attribute? I've used `{{$index}}` within the class - so I know it can print things out within the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing some code, I would assume the number of columns is equal to `resultsObject.length` so can you try:

```
<div class="{{resultsObject.length}} columns" ...
```

Here is a short demo.. Check out the class of each li and you'll see the count.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fFRTjD5gse8tnJmDig2I?p=preview

Lastly can you just try to bind to `class="{{columnCount}} columns">...`  I don't think you need to reference the $rootScope.

Comment: Nice thought. But gives me the same results.

Comment: Can you post a plunkr that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I posted and modified a plunkr from an answer I gave on another question.  If you inspect the list elements you'll see the length of the array object on each element's class.

Comment: Setting everything up in plunkr would take some work. Instead I copied in the relevant code from the controller. Does that help?

Comment: It is confusing with your scope.columncount and rootscope.columncount.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was naming collisions. <doh>. Feel foolish now. It was being overridden in a different part of the app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an issue with variables overlapping. Apparently I had used `columncount` in other places in my app. So it just kept getting set back to an null. Simply changing the name solved the problem.